# ifft2 in matlab still produces complex numbers

Tags: matlab, fft

You I have cell with an 8x8 complex matrix, which holds some secret data, and I converted it back to spatial domain using `ifft2` as follows:

```
F2{i1,j1}=complex(re,Img);

ff{i1,j1}=ifft2(F2{i1,j1});
```

But `ff` still complex (it should be double).
Why is that?

Comment: Is the imaginary part very small compared with the real part? If so, that's caused by numerical precision issues and it's normal; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab). Otherwise, please post a minimal example that we can run

Comment: Unless the matrix has conjugate symmetry, there is no reason to expect a real output.

Comment: If F2{i1,j1} has conjugate symmetry, `ff = ifft2(...,'symmetric')` will make sure the result is real (and possibly slightly speed-up the calculation).